# How I can stop a ProgressBar using two callback?

Tags: java, android, callback

I have a three classes for example View, Logic, Controller.

```
    class View{
    Progressbutton pb;

   void start animation(){
    pb.startAnimation();
    }
   void stopanimation(){
    pb.stopAnimation();
}
}

class Controller{
(it is like a brigdge for View and Logic)
}

    class Logic(){
void startlogic(){...logic is finish}
}
```

I should start animation , then start logic , when logic is finish i need to stop progressButton. How I can do with two callback?

Comment: 2 callback parallel or one by one?

Comment: @HemantParmar 2 callback

Answer (score 1):

You can stop animating pb as :
you define two boolean as bool_callback1 & bool_callback2 and make them false by
default after that make them true whenever your respective callback finishes. and
call a method stopPB() in both callbacks like following:-

```
boolean bool_callback1 = false;
boolean bool_callback2 = false;

callback1() {
    bool_callback1 = true;
    stopPB();
}

callback2() {
    bool_callback2 = true;
    stopPB();
}

stopPB(){
   if (bool_callback1 && bool_callback2) {
        pb.stopAnimation();
    }
}
```